# Obtain a list of customers and their most expensive order details

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

*Please note this database is not real, I have simply phrased the question in am ambiguous way so it can be applied to multiple scenarios.*

So I'm trying to achieve a seemingly simple output: A list of customers in a database, as well as the details of their most expensive order (or blank if no order exists). In my mind it should be as simple as:

```
SELECT Customers.Name, MAX(Orders.Value), Orders.OrderID FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
```

However, this obviously only obtains the MAX value for the column "Orders.Value", and does not necessarily return the associated "Orders.OrderID".

I can achieve the desired result using two queries, whereby I select a list of patients, and then, looping through the results, select the most expensive order for each customer using an ORDER BY. But this seems wildly less efficient than a single JOIN query, even if I have to use a Subquery (which I believe I do).

I know my desired outcome can be achieved using the TOP and ROW_NUMBER functionality in MSSQL, but I'm not sure how to achieve it in MySQL.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Returning all customers is important, even if they have no orders. So doing the SELECT on the Orders and instead JOINING back to Customers is not (I believe) an option.

Comment: Non aggregated column values can be picked from any row. There's no guarantee that the non aggregated values like `order_id` would be picked up from the same row as `Max(order.value)`

Comment: This question is asked and answered endlessly. Just sayin'

Comment: @1000111 I'm aware of that, thus why I have written exactly that in my question.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes Unfortunately I know, and I have searched through countless threads for an answer that efficiently answers my question. If however you feel I've missed one and can point me in the right direction, I'll happily close this one :).

Comment: There is your dupe close. Ditch the New Jersey 'NJ' part of it. Tweak tables accordingly.

Comment: Since the question is closed all I can do is to give you an external [**link**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23239781/). Please give the query a try

Comment: @Drew That answer is not applicable in this scenario due to the need for additional non-aggregated columns to be picked. It will simply pick those values randomly from the joining table.

Comment: @1000111 Thank you very much! This appears to be exactly what I was after. If this question is reopened, please feel free to submit your answer and I'll accept it :).

Comment: @DuncanMcArdle are you saying that your query has more non-aggs that you can add to it and group by it?